# java 8 streams how to convert a Map<String, List<Strings>> to a List<String> will all the string values?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Map<String, List<String>>` map and I want extract from it a `List<String>` that contains the strings of all the list of strings in the map. I'd like to use java8 streams syntax.

In old java I would do:

```
List<String> all = new LinkedList<String>();
for (String key: map.keySet()) {
    all.addAll(map.get(key));
}
return all;
```

how to do that using streams?

Comment: `map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Actually, pre java 8 you would rather do `for (List<String> value : map.values()) {all.addAll(value);}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do what you want using [`Stream.flatMap(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)).

```
public static List<String> collectValues(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
    return map.values().stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

A more generic version could look like:

```
public static <E> List<E> collectValues(Map<?, ? extends Collection<? extends E>> map) {
    return map.values().stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

And an even more generic version which allows you to specify the return type:

```
public static <C extends Collection<E>, E> C collectValues(
        Map<?, ? extends Collection<? extends E>> map, Supplier<C> collectionFactory) {
    return map.values().stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(collectionFactory));
}
```

---

And finally, just for the fun of it, the most generic version I can think of:

```
public static <C, E> C collectValues(Map<?, ? extends Iterable<? extends E>> map, 
                                     Collector<E, ?, C> collector) {
    return map.values().stream()
            .flatMap(iterable -> StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false))
            .collect(collector);
}
```

This one uses the [`StreamSupport`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html) class and [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) interface.

Answer (score 4):

Using a new ArrayList and the addAll() method to get the same result.

```
public class MapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> infoMap = new HashMap<>();
        infoMap.put("1", Arrays.asList("a","b","c"));
        infoMap.put("2", Arrays.asList("d","e","f"));
        infoMap.put("3", Arrays.asList("g","h","i"));

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        infoMap.values().stream().forEach(result::addAll);
        result.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```